# Reputation graphics top value differs from real reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

As I observed,the top value of reputation graphics is higer than real reputation score.
Graphic top value=**3936**
Real score=**3922**
Had it done intentionally to have some 'margin'?

[image]

Comment: Obligatory [should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)...